# Getting the number of region a column family has from hbase shell

Tags: hbase

I want using HBase shell. I want to get the number of regions each column family has, how to get it?

Also what is the default number of regions each column family could have when I create a HBase table?

```
create 't1','c1'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scan 'hbase:meta',{COLUMNS=>'info:server',FILTER=>"PrefixFilter('t1')"}
```

By default, there's a single region per family. When the table is growing, HBase will split the region into 2, then into several regions. The algorithm depends upon the split policy rule. For big tables you may want to pre-split.